# C++ forbids converting a `string` constant to `char*` - Alphabets to Morse converting program

Tags: c++

So i was working on this assignment, i need to convert normal text into Morse code. We're studying basic c++ at the moment so I'm not allowed to use the string data type or any other complex built-in functions.So I tried doing it through a char array. When i try running it,the following error shows up " ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' "

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int len = 0;
char string[45] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.', ',', '?', '[', '!', '(', ')', '&' };
char* morse[45] = { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", "-----", ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", ".-.-.-", "--..--", "..--..", ".----.", "-.-.--", "-..-.", "-.--.", "-.--.-", ".-..." };

void size(char* arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; arr[i] != 0; i++) {
        len++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    cout << "Enter string: ";
    cin.getline(str, 100);
    size(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 45; j++) {
            if (str[i] == string[j]) {
                cout << morse[j];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That error shows up when you ***compile*** the program, not when you ***run*** it.  The difference between compiling and running is very important to understand.

Comment: `string` is not a great name for a variable in C++, particularly if you do something like `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Do not call your variable `string`, especially if you're including `<iostream>`.  Some compilers have remnants of `std::string` being used inside the `<iostream>` headers or headers that `<iostream>` includes.

Comment: @abelenky: That's why it's not a good idea to get NBs into the "press this button and run" IDE philosophy.

Comment: @Zarish -- Off topic, but your solution is not optimal, as you are looping a maximum of 45 * length_of_string.  If the string is 100 characters, you could be looping a maximum of 4500 times.  What would usually be done is use a `std::map` that would map the character to the morse code symbol, so that you're not doing a one-by-one lookup to see which morse symbol matches the character.

Comment: You forgot  to assigned the length of str to len

Comment: @willll, The global `len` is initialized once, and `size` increments it.  It will work once, but of course, there is a cleaner way to do it (reset `len` inside `size` before incrementing), or better yet, return the length from `size`.

Answer (score 27):

You're defining an array of `char*` objects. You initialize those pointers with string literals. But as the error explains, converting a string literal (called *constant* by the compiler) to `char*` is not allowed.

Solution: Converting a string literal to `const char*` is allowed, so you could declare an array of `const char*` instead. You don't appear to modify the strings pointed by the array, so this shouldn't be a problem.

---

PS. You've chosen to include a standard library header, and have chosen to use `using namespace std;` and defined an identifier with the same name as an identifier declared by the standard library (`string`). That will very likely be a problem for the compiler.

Solution: Do not use `using namespace std`.

Workaround: Come up with another variable name than `string`. The trick is to know all identifiers declared by the standard library. Since this trick isn't trivial and new identifiers will be added in future versions of the standard, I recommend the solution above instead.

Comment: I changed the variable name from string to string1 and changed char* to const char*. **now** there are no errors. But i'm only asked to enter a string and it ends. I get no output.

Answer (score 5):

The issue, as described in the error, is that `"..."`, for example, is a string constant and you are trying to assign to a non-constant `char*`. Instead you should be assigning to a `const char*`:

```
const char* morse[45] = { ".-" // ...
```

Comment: I tried doing that. Now it says " reference to 'string' is ambiguous
       if (str[i]==string[j])"

Comment: @Zarish that would be a different question, but my guess is that it is related to the comment by Neil Butterworth above.